# How to update video playing current time using ajax in laravel

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel

```html
<script> 
  var vid = document.getElementById("player"); 
  $(function() {
    var timeout;
    $("#player").on("playing pause", function(e) {
      // Save reference
      var v = this

      // Clear previous timeout, if any
      clearTimeout(timeout)

      // Call immediately if paused or when started
      performaction(v.currentTime, v.duration)
      
      // Set up interval to fire every 5 seconds
      if (e.type === "playing") {
        timeout = setInterval(function() {
          performaction(v.currentTime, v.duration)
        }, 5000)
      }
    })
  
    function performaction(currentTime, duration) {
      console.log(currentTime);
      console.log(' ajax action goes here');
      var data = { pause_time : currentTime };
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/instructor/promo_video/84',
        data: data,
        success: function() {
          console.log("Value added");
        }
      })
    }
  })
</script>
```

> In my database I have a video table in which I have a column name as `pause_time`.
> Now if I use this js code for video current playing time then I am getting the time after 5 seconds interval in the console.
> I want to send this time to the database using ajax in laravel. And also how to take the `currentTime` value in the controller.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

If you created a video table, then you should make a video model:

```
php artisan make:model Video
```

When you're using POST methods in frontend, you need to pass a CSRF token too.

```js
const data = {
  _token: YOUR_TOKEN,
  pause_time : currentTime,
};
```

To get data from database, you should use ORM, so:

```php
$video = Video::where(SOME_CONDITIONS, value)->first();
$currentTime = $video->pause_time;
```

To get data from frontend, you should use $request:

```php
public function yourController(Request $request)
{
    $currentTime = $request->pause_time;
}
```

Comment: But could u tell me in detail. I tried it but stil not. And also tell me that how the video current time will get uploaded automatically using ajax. If possible would u be give me a code for that. Thankfull for ur reply

Comment: 1. https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent
2. https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/setInterval